# whats the difference between dot operator and scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, scope-resolution

I just wanted to know the difference between . operator and :: operator?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The former (dot, `.`) is used to access members of an object, the latter (double colon, `::`) is used to access members of a namespace or a class.

Consider the following setup.

```
namespace ns {
    struct type
    {
        int var;
    };
}
```

In this case, to refer to the structure, which is a member of a namespace, you use `::`. To access the variable in an object of type `type`, you use `.`.

```
ns::type obj;
obj.var = 1;
```

Comment: so, if we are using object to access something, then we have to use dot operator, and if we are using a class name then we have to use ::, right?, can you give an example also, if u dont mind!

Comment: @oDx, that is correct, so if you have a static variable or function of a class, you would use "::" with the name of the class to reference them, whereas if you have a member function or member variable, you would use "." with the name of an instance of the class.

Comment: Based on your example, is this basically the same? ```ns.type.var = 1```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think of the quad-dot '::' is the `scope resolution operator.` In cases where there are more than one object in scope that have the same name. You explicitly declare which one to use:

```
 std::min(item, item2);
```

or

```
mycustom::min(item, item2);
```

The dot operator '.' is to call methods and attributes of an object instance

```
Myobject myobject;
myobject.doWork();
myobject.count = 0;
// etc
```

It was not asked, but there is another operator to use if an object instance
is created dynamically with `new`, it is the arrow operator '->'

```
Myobject myobject2 = new Myobject();
myobject2->doWork();
myobject2->count = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a pointer to an object instance, you'll have to access the members of the object using -> in place of "dot"

Comment: You don't *have to* -- `p->m` is just syntactic sugar for `(*p).m` ;)